# Can I specify the permission when posting status through Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I post a status through the graph api, I can then retrieve the status through "me/feed" or "me/home". But now the newly posted status can only be retrieved through "me/home".

By checking the status's origin data, I found the posted status has the following privacy:

```
   "privacy": {
      "description": "Friends",
      "value": "ALL_FRIENDS"
   },
```

When I post message through Facebook WEB, I can choose the privacy, which can be one of PUBLIC, FRIENDS, ONLY ME or CUSTOMER. Can I do the same thing with the Graph API?

Comment: I'm wondering why the status that posted through Facebook Graph API Explorer has a PUBLIC privacy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like:

```
$wallpost = $facebook->api('me/feed','post',array(
  'name'        => 'Headline',
  'message'     => '',
  'privacy'     => array(
      'value'   => 'CUSTOM',
      'friends' => 'EVERYONE'
   )....
```

Comment: Yes. But Are there any document of Graph API about this?